# document.getElementById() problem

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line of code:

```
<a href="#" id="profilelink" name="profilelink" 
    value="<?php echo $id."/".$block_record;?>" 
    onClick="return viewornot(<?php echo $id; ?>)">
   <?php echo $uniqueCode; ?>
</a>
```

So with the onclick i want to pass the id concatenated with a blocked id to my JS:

```
function viewornot()
{
    var val = document.getElementById('profilelink');
    var e = confirm('Do you want to view this profile?');

    if (e == true)
    { 
       //for live site
       window.location.href = "http://www.rainbowcode.net/index.php/profiles/showprofilepersonal?id="+id;
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //if val contains a 1 then user is blocked
        //display a message then
    }
    return false
}
```

the line: `var val = document.getElementById('profilelink');` is not giving me what I want
it should contain the user id concatenated with a 1(blocked) or 0(not blocked)
`($id."/".$blocked_user)`

can someone help me please?
thank you

Comment: `id` may be not unique in your page ?? and which IE version u r working with??

Comment: id is correct i tested it and i run chromium

Comment: He means that if you have more than one of those links on the page then you should be using `class` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
var val = document.getElementById('profilelink');
```

You're actually working with the DOM element that is your link. What you actually want is the parameter that is being passed to your method.

Change your method signature

```
function viewornot(blockedStatus) {
   var val = blockedStatus;
   //your code
}
```

You might also want to change your link

```
<a href="#" id="profilelink" name="profilelink" 
    value="<?php echo $id."/".$block_record;?>" 
  -->   onClick="return viewornot('<?php echo $id."/".$block_record;?>')">
   <?php echo $uniqueCode; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: yikes my bad! sorry...i forgot the ' in the viewornot(' ..... ')
  working now thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementById('profilelink')` returns a reference to the DOM, not the value attribute you have specified (*which is invalid HTML*).

change that to <strike>`document.getElementById('profilelink').value`</strike> (*might fail in compliant browsers because value is not a valid attribute for a tag*)

or

```
document.getElementById('profilelink').getAttribute('value');
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/EWdLD/

---

**Additionally**, you most likely want to change the `viewornot()` definition to `viewornot(id)` since you seem to pass that as a parameter, and use it inside your method.

---

**Security wise**, i hope you do not use this for real security as it is easily bypassed by manipulating the DOM in the client. For more robust security use some server-side code to block/unblock per request.

Answer (score 2):

Not to point out the obvious, but `val` is not the actual value. You need `document.getElementById('profilelink').value` to do that.

Comment: thanks all but totally confused now,here my full code:
    <?php
    foreach ($freechat_list as $r)
    {
       $uniqueCode = substr($r,0,12);
       $id = substr($r,13);
       $blocked_record = RcBlockListTablePeer::isBlocked($id,$requestor_id);
       ?>                                 
       <a href="#" id="profilelink" name="profilelink"  onClick="return viewornot(<?php echo $id."/".$blocked_record; ?>)"><?php echo $uniqueCode; ?></a>
    }
my JS:
    function viewornot(id)
    {
       alert(id);
    }
alert(id) only gives me id but i concatenated it with blocked_record please help?

Answer (score 0):

`a` tags don't have a value attribute.  You need to pass this value to the function.

```
<a href="#" id="profilelink" name="profilelink" onClick="return viewornot(<?php echo $block_record; ?>)"><?php echo $uniqueCode; ?></a>
```

Comment: i have it like this but i want to pass a concatenated value and in my js when i do a alert(id) i only get id and not the concatenated value
viewornot(<?php echo $id."/".$blocked_record; ?>)

Answer (score 0):

In the `<a>` tag there is no `"value"` attribute was available you can pass as parameter with another parameter as pass

For example:

```
<a onclick="view(<?php echo id ?>)</a>

<script>
   function view(id){
         alert(id);
   }
</script>
```

Try this way

Comment: i only get id and not the rest i concatenated id with

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping the link creation script, every link will have an id of `profilelink`.  You can solve this by adding the database id to the end of id in the anchor tag.  It would be better to pass everything through the function and not worry about making a variable of the anchor.

Comment: oooo right i do run the link in a loop listing users so if you click on a user it must run the onclick and pass some values so i can check it in the js to decide which message i must display... will my href link look like this now???? 

    <a href="#" id="<?php echo $id."/".$block_record;?>" name="profilelink"  onClick="return viewornot(<?php echo $id; ?>)"><?php echo $uniqueCode; ?></a>

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ahref can not have a value. Just pass the "val" through the onclick function. "val" will be passed through the function and then you do not need to getElementById

```
<a href="#" id="profilelink" name="profilelink" onClick="viewornot(<?php echo $id; ?>)"><?php echo $uniqueCode; ?></a>
```

.

```
    function viewornot(val)
    {

    var e = confirm('Do you want to view this profile?');

    if (e == true)
    { 
       //for live site
       window.location.href = "http://www.rainbowcode.net/index.php/profiles/showprofilepersonal?id="+id;
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //if val contains a 1 then user is blocked
        //display a message then
    }
    return false
}
```